# Include after Union method not working (Entity Framework Core 2)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-core

I have this simple code, using EF Core 2.

I perform 2 subqueries and the result is the **Union** of them. The problem is that the `Include` method in after the `Union` doesn't load the navigation properties (`Role` is always `null`).

```
public static void Main() 
{
     using (var context = new MyDbContext()) 
     {
         IQueryable<User> a = SomeQuery(context);
         IQueryable<User> b = SomeOtherQuery(context);

         var union = a.Union(b);
         var resultingList = union.Include(x => x.Role); // Include doesn't work
     }    
}
```

What should I do to effectively load navigation properties after composing with the Union method?

NOTE: The problem also happens with the `Concat` method.

Comment: cast `ToList()` I tried here and it works.  `var resultingList = union.Include(x => x.Role).ToList();`

Comment: It worked! but why?

Comment: IQueryable provides a query to execute, does not execute it

[Docs here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562(v=vs.110).aspx)

and [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattwar/2007/07/30/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-i/) you can see more About Linq and IQueryable

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing the IQueryable out of the context of the MyDbContext object. There is no db connection at that time. Make sure you do all db access withing the context of the MyDbContext (using scope):

```
 public IEnumarable<User> GetItems() 
 {
   IEnumarable<User> resultingList;
   using (var context = new MyDbContext()) 
   {
     IQueryable<User> a = SomeQuery(context);
     IQueryable<User> b = SomeOtherQuery(context);

     var union = a.Union(b);
     resultingList = union.Include(x => x.Role).ToList();
   }   
   return resultingList; 
 }
```